# Axios for page crawling. Cannot pass a variable url

Tags: node.js, express, npm, web-scraping, axios

I'm using Axios to crawl a page but I need to initialise the url and can't pass a variable via a form. I'm trying to send the url via an input form but I cannot change the url. And when I place the axios call in a function, I get a lexical error. Can this be achieved via Axios? Or am I using the wrong tool?

Just need to be able to pass a url via a form submit and return the data.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example